# How to draw transparent circles on Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to draw circles on the Google Maps API, which are transparent.

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(lat, lon))
        .radius(50.0)
        .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        .strokeWidth(1)
        .fillColor(Color.CYAN); //
```

But I like to draw them transparently, so that I can see the map behind? How could I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For mGoogleMap as `GoogleMap` object, with latitude longitude given as

```
LatLng currentLatLon = new LatLng(lat double value, lng double value);
```

This is the way to draw circle in google maps

```
mGoogleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(currentLatLon)
                    .radius(150)
                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                    .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                    .strokeWidth(5)
                    );
```

Comment: Yes you're right. The RGB color codes are 0000FF and the transparency layer is in the beginning 0x22. I tought it was the last byte pair.

Comment: Since when has the transparency channel been AA and not DD in 0xAABBCCDD? That is so wrong! But thank you for letting us know!

Answer (score 5):

**This will add the transparent circle around the marker**

```
Circle mCircle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                 .center(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()))
                 .radius(500)
                 .strokeWidth(0)
                 .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#2271cce7"))
                 .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#2271cce7")));
```

For the Transparent Color you can set it to any Color using i.e **#2271cce7**

In the above the actual color code is **#71cce7** and the first two digits of **22** indicate the transparency which can be set to any value to either increase or decrease transparency.

[View Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRSaC.png)